# telegram bot not showing time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

saya sedang membuat fungsi "tambah" dan pada saat di jalankan fungsi tersebut berhasil akan tetapi variable "waktu" tidak muncul dan row pada "pola[3]" tidak bisa di bold , bagaimana caranya biar data waktu muncul ke spreadsheet dan pada row ke tiga bisa di bold ke telegram?

I'm making the "tambah" function and when I run the function it works but the "time" variable doesn't appear and the row in "pola[3]" can't be bolded, how do I get the time data to appear in the spreadsheet and in the third row can it be bolded to telegram?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUupR.png)

```html
function tambah(cid,cmd){
  var txt = '';
  var pola = cmd.match(/tambah#(.+)#(.+)#(.+)/);
  Logger.log(pola);
  if (pola[1]!='' && pola[2]!='' && pola[3]!='') {
    var uji = cek(pola[1]);
    if (uji == '') {
      var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
      var ss = ws.getSheetByName('material');
      ss.appendRow([pola[1],pola[2],pola[3]]);
      txt = 'Material '+pola[1]+' Jumlah '+pola[2]+' dan Satuan ''<b>' +pola[3]+ '</b>\n'' berhasil ditambahkan...';
      var now = new Date();
      var waktu = Utilities.formatDate(now, "Asia/Jakarta", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
      sendMessage(cid,txt,waktu);
    } else {
      txt = 'Sudah ditemukan '+uji;
      sendMessage(cid,txt,waktu);
    }
  } else {
    txt = 'Pola salah';
    Logger.log(txt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kamu cukup menambahkkan `new Date()` pada `ss.appendRow`

```html
ss.appendRow([pola[1],pola[2],pola[3], new Date()]);
```

dan hasilnya akan seperti ini

```html
function tambah(cid,cmd){
  var txt = '';
  var pola = cmd.match(/tambah#(.+)#(.+)#(.+)/);
  Logger.log(pola);
  if (pola[1]!='' && pola[2]!='' && pola[3]!='') {
    var uji = cek(pola[1]);
    if (uji == '') {
      var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
      var ss = ws.getSheetByName('material');
      ss.appendRow([pola[1],pola[2],pola[3], new Date()]);
      txt = 'Material '+pola[1]+' Jumlah '+pola[2]+' dan Satuan ' +pola[3]+' berhasil ditambahkan...';
//      var waktu = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Asia/Jakarta", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
      sendMessage(cid,txt);
    } else {
      txt = 'Sudah ditemukan '+uji;
      sendMessage(cid,txt);
    }
  } else {
    txt = 'Pola salah';
    Logger.log(txt);
  }
}
```

Comment: terimakasih telah membantu, akan tetapi untuk hasil bold belum terpenuhi bang @Newbie